# Python MySQL Is there a way to pull pure data for comparing numeric values?

Tags: python, mysql

I am now learning to use Python with MySQL and I just can't find any way to pull *just* the numeric value of something in my database table.

Using

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT price FROM store WHERE fruit = apple")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

but that would return

```
('10',)
```

And so I want to compare the price of apples to oranges but I can't if I have that extra fluff on the sides.

So I am hoping someone can enlighten me on a method to remove that fluff whether we wanna extract an integer or string

Comment: That query would fail, is that the real query

Comment: This is a tuple with a single item. To retrieve the actual item, use `x[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp=[]

for x in myresult:
    tmp.append(str(x).strip("(),"))

print(tmp[0])
```

im not sure if you'll need to retrieve multiple values at once but this should work